# SELECT clause with two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Find which of the following departments: IT,RESEARCH has its locations in all cities included in CITY column of DEPTLOC table

Having a deptloc table

```
//DEPTLOC
CITY           DNAME
---------------------------
NEW YORK       ACCOUNTING
SAN FRA           IT
BOSTON         OPERATIONS
BOSTON         RESEARCH
DALLAS         RESEARCH
LOS ANGELES    RESEARCH
```

Department Table

```
DNAME
----------
ACCOUNTING
IT
OPERATIONS
RESEARCH
```

What is the meant by the " has its locations in all cities included in CITY column of DEPTLOC table"

Comment: I'd have though that was pretty self explanatory. What is it you REALLY want to know? This has the whiff of an assignment question.

Comment: Looking for help with homework?  LOL.  Here it comes:  the `deptloc` table (as you've shown it) has 5 cities in it.  (1) Is the "IT" department located in all 5 of those cities?  (2) Is the "RESEARCH" department located in all 5 of those cities?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
SELECT A.DNAME
FROM (SELECT  DNAME, 
              COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) CITIES
      FROM DEPTLOC
      GROUP BY DNAME) A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) CITIES
            FROM DEPTLOC) B
WHERE A.CITIES = B.CITIES
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62a0e/6) with a demo.

Comment: @Kermit lol, yeah, you are right. Happy to oblige if the community decides to close/delete it. I answered it mainly to see if I can write an oracle query (and it was harder than I thought)

Comment: Also: `SELECT DNAME FROM DEPTLOC GROUP BY DNAME HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) FROM DEPTLOC) ;`

Comment: @ypercube yeah, much better. I tried that in sqlfiddle and kept getting errors and then I gave up

Answer (score -3):

i think your query is :

```
SELECT * FROM DEPTLOC
WHERE DNAME IN('IT','RESEARCH')
GROUP BY (CITY,DNAME);
```